# Why is entrepreneurship a factor of production?

Tags: economic-growth

I'm a student at a faculty of economics. The professor asked us a question to which I still can not find an answer, which is why entrepreneurship is part of the production factors?
I would be very grateful to you!

Comment: You should probably include more context to get a good answer.

Comment: For example, how did your professor define production factors and entrepreneurship?  Were these in contrast to other terms?  What research did you do to try to answer this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Every ship needs someone at the wheel. The sea is rough and there is a lot of fog around. That makes it difficult to steer. 
Entrepreneurship is hard to measure, so it exists in many econonic models as invisible part of factors labor, knowledge and capital.